# PLSQL_trigger_check duplicate account number has erros

Tags: plsql

Trying to create a trigger that prevents duplicate acct# and null acct balance. Trigger is able to create but when inserting an duplicate acct# to test the trigger, got error mesg that "trigger is invalid and failed re-validation".

```
create or replace trigger update_acct#  
before insert or update on ACCOUNT  
for each row  
declare
    v_cta# NUMBER;    
begin  
    select count(:new.A#) into v_cta# from account group by A#;   
    if (v_cta#>1 or :new.bal=null) then     
        raise_application_error (-20011, 'DUPLICATE ACCOUNT NUMBER OR BAL CANNOT BE NULL');                    
    end if;  
end;
```

Comment: Why not use unique constraint?

Comment: I didn't learn unique constraint but will look it up. In this case, I was just trying to practice on creating triggers and really hope someone could point out my errors so that I could learn how to check duplicates in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely positively do not want to use a trigger for this.  Use a unique constraint to prevent duplicate account numbers.

```
ALTER TABLE account ADD CONSTRAINT a#_unique UNIQUE (a#);
```

Make your balance field not accept nulls.

```
ALTER TABLE account MODIFY bal NOT NULL;
```

For purely educational purposes here is how you'd implement this with your trigger.  Yours was close, except you want to use :new.a# to count rows and not have it expressly in the COUNT() and that you want an AFTER trigger since you want to see if your newly added account is the first duplicate.

```
create or replace trigger update_acct#  
after insert or update on ACCOUNT  
for each row  
DECLARE
  v_cta# INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_cta#
    FROM account
   WHERE a# = :new.a#;

  IF v_cta# > 1 OR :new.bal = NULL THEN
    raise_application_error(-20011,
                            'DUPLICATE ACCOUNT NUMBER OR BAL CANNOT BE NULL');
  END IF;
END update_acct#;
/
```